# Loading a library by default in python

Tags: python

I often used python as a library and it could save me some time if I could use an alias to launch python and tell him to load the math module at the same time (ideally in the same way as *from math import **) Is there a command line argument for that?

It doesn't look like much but that would save me from doing something really repetitive. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this on the command line is using the `-c` (execute command) and `-i` (run interactively after executing script/command) options.

```
$ python -i -c 'from math import *'
>>> sin(pi/2)
1.0
```